# how to configure USB mounted WiFi WLAN Adapter

Tags: networking, wireless, usb

I have a WiFi USB adapter/router . This adapter is using Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8191SU.  and supports WLAN 802.11n

the output of `lsusb` gives me the following output

```
ID 0bda:8172 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8191SU 802.11n WLAN Adapter
```

So far is is showing its led in slow blink mode, indicating that hardware has been detected.

I want to know as how to configure it as a wireless network, in infrastructure mode.

Comment: Can you post the output of the following 3 commands : dmesg | tail lsmod sudo iwconfig

Comment: What is your actual problem that doesn't let you configure it through GUI or terminal as usual? Or are you asking a general question how to configure such a device? (We seem to have no question with an answer to that currently.)

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know as how to configure it as a wireless network, in
>   infrastructure mode.

I believe what you want is to configure it as an Access Point, is that right? The steps are the following:

- find out the name of your usb dongle ( i.e, wlan1, wlan2 ) through `iwconfig`
- `sudo ifconfig wlanX down`
- `sudo iwconfig wlanX mode Master`
- `sudo ifconfig wlanX up`

Basically , bring the interface down, change mode, bring back up.

If this is not exactly what you want, please add explanation into comment bellow or into your question; also, rate this question up if it was useful

Comment: Hit-and-run question!  ;-)  Still a good answer!